# The algebra generated by the intervals of $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

> $X = \mathbf{R}$
>
> The algebra generated by the intervals consists of all subsets of $\mathbf{R}$ that are the union of a finite number of intervals.
>
> This can also be described as the smallest algebra of subsets of $\mathbf{R}$ that contains all the intervals.

I am just starting Measure Theory but I don't 'get' the last sentence. Surely the algebra generated by the intervals is infinitely large...so how can it be described as 'smallest algebra of subsets of $\mathbf{R}$ that contains all the intervals'?

Answer (score 1):

Smallest does not mean finite. When you say that $A$ is the smallest algebra of subsets of $\Bbb R$ that contains all the intervals, you're claiming that for any other algebra $B$ that contains all the intervals you have $A\subset B$.

Comment: OK just so I am 100% clear on it - if I have $A$, the smallest algebra of subsets of $\Bbb R$ that contains all the intervals, and I unioned it with a one element set S = {1}...would $A \bigcup S$ suffice as an algebra $B$ such that $A\subset B$?

Comment: Actually, I think a one element set 'is' an interval so lets say $S = (0, 1) \bigcup (2, 3)$ which is not an interval. Would $A \subset B$ be true if $B = A \bigcup S$?

Comment: Note that $A$ is a collection of subsets of $\Bbb R$, what you want to write is $A\cup \{(0,1)\cup (2,3)\}$. Since i) $A$ is an algebra, ii) $(0,1)\in A$, and iii) $(2,3)\in A$, you must have $(0,1)\cup (2,3)\in A$. So $A=A\cup\{(0,1)\cup (2,3)\}$.

Comment: OK cheers, I really need to sharpen up on this stuff! Have you got any example of something I can union with $A$ to give a 'larger' algebra of subsets $B$ such that $A \subset B$?

Comment: You can take $a=(1,2)\cup (2,3)\cup\cdots =\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}(n,n+1)$ and set $B$ equals the algebra  generated by $A\cup\{a\}$. (edited).

Comment: Ah, so you are throwing in an infinite union of intervals, cheers!

Comment: That's right. Have fun.